# Connection attempt timeout on dbeaver with SSH connection to remote postres databse

Tags: postgresql, ssh, dbeaver

Using dbeaver, I'm trying to connect to a postgres database through a SSH tunnel. I've setup the SSH configuration by introducing my private key and passphrase and test tunnel is good. But I get a timeout when I test connection to the database. (test connection works fine without SSH)
Can anyone help me please?
Thanks!

Comment: @jjanes the host server is an Ubuntu.

Comment: What is in the "Host" box of the "Server" section of the "Main" tab in the connection configuration dialog?  Is it 'localhost'?  '127.0.0.1'? something else?

Comment: It's the IP address of the database server, I can ping it and telnet it on both ports 22 and 5432.

Comment: Can you ping it etc. from the machine where the tunnel ends up?

Comment: Thanks for your help jjanes. Yes I can pint it and telnet it from localhost too.

Comment: The *other* end of the tunnel should not be localhost.  Why have a tunnel to itself?

Comment: I mean I can ping from my machine and from localhost too (both ports are responding).

Comment: In the Main section, I have the IP address of the database server (I have a successful test connection here). in the SSH section, I have the same IP address, my username, the authentication method is "public key", I've inserted the path to the private key, the passphrase and selected the SSHJ implementation. (I have a successful test tunnel connection.) But when I tick "use SSH tunnel" and test the connection I get a connection timeout. That's why I'm really confused.